# Characters truncated using varchar(max) type

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In my stored proc, I am creating dynamic query and storing in table variable(records will be output of dynamic query) such that that table variable will have almost 1000 records. Then I am concatenating all rows to form single string value. My issue is after concatenating,  characters are getting truncated as a result of which creating view `V_Market` is failing because complete create view syntax is missing from exec. I have attached sample code here.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @PMC TABLE 
( 
    sqql VARCHAR(max) 
 ); 

INSERT INTO @PMC --storing dynamic queries in table
SELECT 'Select p.ID,Order_of,Field_Name, VALUE, Val from( Select  ' 
       + Cast(id AS VARCHAR(5)) 
       + ' D ,''' 
       + Cast(order_of AS CHAR(3)) 
       + ''' Order_of, ''' +ltrim(rtrim(field_name)) 
       + ''' Field_Name,sum(CAST(' + ltrim(rtrim(field_name)) 
       + ' as float)) VALUE,  ' + Val 
       + ' Val from Market  where  roll_id =21)P  ' sqql   
FROM   Market_config 

SELECT @Names = COALESCE(@Names + 'Union ', '') + sqql 
FROM   @PMC --concatenating all rows to form single string value

SELECT @Names = 'CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Market] AS ' 
                + @Names 
SELECT @Names  --charactrs truncated in @Names variable

EXEC (@Names) -- CREATE VIEW [dbo].[V_Market] failing from here because @Names has incomplete syntax
```

Comment: Could you add Market_config table create script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the first line:

```
SELECT 'Select p.ID,Order_of,Field_Name, VALUE, Val from( Select  '
```

to be:

```
SELECT CAST('Select p.ID,Order_of,Field_Name, VALUE, Val from( Select  ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
```

because when you concatenating `varchar` strings which are not explicitly max (cast as max or exceed 4000 chars) the results is not converting automatically to one with max length.

For example, let's concatenate two 4000 chars + additional chars:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'SELECT REPLICATE(''A'', 4000) + REPLICATE(''B'', 4000) + ''This will be cut'' AS [X]'
```

The result is variable with type `VARCHAR(8000)`.

Also, you might need to add such conversion in the rest of the statements.